# Avoiding fat view models strategy

Tags: android, android-fragments

Lets say I got an activity that manage a long process compounded of 7 fragments. each fragment has it's own view logic, and passes to the next fragment when user moving through the process the activity represents.

I can make 1 shared view model which will hold all data that needs to be displayed in all fragments, but I'd like to avoid it.

So I want to create a different view model for each fragment and a view model for the activity, to manage the flow.

My question is, is this the proper way? cause in android architecture blueprints, there is no proper example for this kind of case.

And lets say its good, how does the fragment view models should communicate with the activity view model? is a service layer that share data between them (with live data) is good enough?

Comment: I think that activity should only handle fragments, fragments should then handle their own view models

Comment: @SarthakMittal yeah, that might be a good idea for straight fwd process.. what if decision of next fragment depends on state of current Fragment's viewmodel?

Comment: @HBB20 apologies for the delayed reply, you can use nav-graph for that, either a single activity architecture or having sub-graphs should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Taking in mind single responsibility, use shared ViewModels only when needed, aim to have one ViewModel for one view.

If the ViewModel-for-one-fragment is getting fatter and fatter, it's time to take a detour to granulating the responsibilities into smaller viewmodels. Such as ViewModel for particular UI part (list, card) of the fragment that will exempt the initial fat ViewModel for your fragment, some of the properties and logic.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, is this the proper way?

I'd say so, yes. I think you should mimic your view structure in your view models. So you would have *one* ActivityViewModel and *one* FragmentViewModel *per child fragment*. Then your ActivityViewModel owns each fragment view model to do the necessary coordination between the fragments.

> And lets say its good, how does the fragment view models should communicate with the activity view model? is a service layer that share data between them (with live data) is good enough?

Yes. Observe the relevant states of each view model and then send messages to the ones that should update.

Trivial Example:

```
class ActivityViewModel() {

    private val fragViewModel1: FragmentViewModel1
    private val fragViewModel2: FragmentViewModel2

    init {
        fragViewModel1.someLiveData.observe {
            fragViewModel2.updateViewStateBasedOnFragment1(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously how you initialize and set all these view models is another issue, but hopefully this helps you get started.

Hope that helps!